# I would like to get via Ajax the result of a request in PHP without displaying the JSON in the web page

Tags: php, ajax

I use Ajax to get the result of a request in a PHP script with 'echo'.
But this 'echo' displays this result (a JSON) in my web page.
How can I avoid this ?

I have found no answer on internet.

PHP :

```
if ( !isset($_POST['nomSaisiRecherche']) || $_POST['nomSaisiRecherche'] == '' ){
    $rechercheDeclarationsSansFiltre = 
        rechercheDeclarationsSansFiltre(LARGEUR_BOUTONS_DECLARATIONS * LONGUEUR_BOUTONS_DECLARATIONS);
    if ($rechercheDeclarationsSansFiltre == ERREUR){
        echo ERREUR_REQUETE;
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode($rechercheDeclarationsSansFiltre);
    }
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'accesseurs/declarations.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data:{nomSaisiRecherche:''},
        success:function(data){
            if (data != <?php echo ERREUR_REQUETE ?>){
                // do things
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: could you please explain the issue more

Comment: Nothing here displays anything on the web page. Whatever the PHP script echoes will become the value of `data`, and it will only be displayed if the `success` function does that.

Comment: @Barnar : but I can see it, and the success function does nothing with the brute data.

Comment: My fault : I had written '<?php include_once(script for the request); ?>' in the PHP managing the HTML. Sorry for the trouble and the lack of clarity

Answer (score 0):

first you would select the place you want to print in in my case i want to 
print the result in `ul` has `id` of `result`

```
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

your code will be something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = $('#result');
    var result = '';
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'accesseurs/declarations.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data:{nomSaisiRecherche:''},
        success:function(data){
            if (data != <?php echo ERREUR_REQUETE ?>){
               data.forEach(el => { 
                    result += `<li>${el.title}</li>`
               });
               list.text = result;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

in this part i make loop in the data become from your request if i guess it would be array of objects you can chnage it depending on you data `type`

```
data.forEach(el => { 
    result += `<li>${el.title}</li>`
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I don't want to print evrything, only some fields depending on the situation. But with your exemple I guess that I can write <ul id="result" hidden></ul>. Am I wrong ? (Sorry I don't manage to newline)

Comment: Sorry, I would have liked to edit my previous comment but I have not been fast enough. I don't understand how to link the HTML with the result of the PHP script executing the request.